# Found most pair product in a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I tried to retrieve most appear pair product in one transaction from a transaction table

the table contains :

- row_id = as primary key
- kode_transaksi = transaction id
- kode_pelanggan = customers id
- no_urut = seq of transaction
- kode_produk = products id
- nama_produk = products name
- qty = number of buy
- harga = price per unit
  [image: Sample data]

the result must contain name of product 1 from most pair product and name of product2 where the name must ascending also numbers of transaction of pair product
[image: Result]

Here is far I tried

```
select 
        *,
        max(tab1.total) 
from
    (
        select
            tp.kode_transaksi as kode_transaksi,
            tp.kode_produk,
            tp.nama_produk,
            tp.qty,
                sum(tp.qty) as total
        from tr_penjualan tp
        group by tp.kode_produk 
    ) tab1
left join
    (
        select
            tp2.kode_transaksi as kode_transaksi,
            tp2.kode_produk,
            tp2.nama_produk,
            tp2.qty,
            sum(tp2.qty) as total
        from tr_penjualan tp2
        group by tp2.kode_produk 
    ) tab2
 on tab1.kode_produk = tab2.kode_produk
group by tab1.kode_produk
having tab1.kode_produk = tab2.kode_produk
order by tab1.kode_transaksi;
```

I'm stuck because don't know to merge the pair that in a transaction.
Thanks before

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana I upload the picture

Comment: still I'm not clear on what are you trying to achieve , are you trying to find the products that are most bought together ?

Comment: @eshirvana Exactly

Comment: @AhmadRoyhan - instead of screenshot can you paste sql code that are reusable?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , here is one way to find out which couple products are bought together the most:

```
select tp1.kode_produk 
     , tp2.kode_produk 
     , count(*) boughttogether
from tr_penjualan tp1
inner join tr_penjualan tp2
    on tp1.kode_transaksi = tp2.kode_transaksi
    and tp1.kode_produk <> tp2.kode_produk
group by 
    tp1.kode_produk 
  , tp2.kode_produk 
order by count(*) desc
```